# How to get a double quote as a completion option?

Tags: bash, bash-completion

I tried

```
COMPREPLY=( '"' )
```

but in command line I get `\"` instead. Is getting just a single double quote as a completion option possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, getting just a single double quote as a completion option is not possible (as far as I know).

The completion options are shown in the form (or a form) in which they would need to be typed, and in order to get a single double quote, you would have to type `\"`, so that's what bash shows you.